# How to use ajax response JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have made my ajax request, which works great and returns JSON.

But how do i use it?

My response is something like this

```
[{
    "id": "5",
    "reviewID": "2389",
    "serviceID": "50707",        
    "title": "well done"
}]
```

Now in my success function I am trying to use the data like such:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('Success Alert');
    $('#myModalLabel').text('Review:' + data.title);
},
```

This just shows

```
[object Object]
```

How can I use this data?

Comment: The returned JSON will be deserialised to an array of objects, so you need to access `data` by index, for example: `data[0].title`

Comment: From the given response data.title will give you `undefined` not `[object Object] `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `data` is `array` of `objects`, use `data[0].title`:

```
$('#myModalLabel').text('Review:' + data[0].title);
//                                      ^^^
```